# Detecting Mobile Device in Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, device

I'm having a spring boot application. I am trying to figure out the type of the device the request has been instantiated.

I have added the spring mobile device as an jar in pom.xml

pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

ControllerConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class ControllerConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver deviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver() {
    return new DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
}

@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
     argumentResolvers.add(new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(
             new DeviceWebArgumentResolver()));
         argumentResolvers
             .add(new SitePreferenceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
}
}
```

I have a controller class that uses the device as the request parameter.

Controller.java :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/device",method=RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
  public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getDeviceInfo(Device device){
    if (device != null && device.isNormal()) {
            System.out.println("*******normal******");
        }else if(device != null && (device.isMobile() || device.isTablet())){
            System.out.println("*******mobile******");
        }
  }
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mobile.device.Device]: Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) ~[javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) ~[undertow-core-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) ~[undertow-core-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) ~[undertow-core-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) ~[undertow-core-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) ~[undertow-servlet-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) ~[undertow-core-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_40]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.mobile.device.Device]: Specified class is an interface
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:101) ~[spring-beans-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:140) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:79) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:106) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:77) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:162) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:129) ~[spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:706) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
... 32 common frames omitted
```

Is there any way to resolve this error.?

Answer (score 2):

Although you have declared a `DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` bean, you have not added it as a required resolver in `addArgumentResolvers`.  Your code should be:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
  argumentResolvers.add(deviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());

  argumentResolvers.add(new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(new DeviceWebArgumentResolver()));

  argumentResolvers.add(new SitePreferenceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
}
```

You should also consider declaring `SitePreferenceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and `ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter` as beans.